# Toolbar, onCreateOptionsMenu() returns false, 'up' navigation not working

Tags: android, android-menu, android-toolbar

I'm using the new Toolbar on Lollipop (no support library). My activity has a list and if the list is empty, I don't want to show any options menu. My implementation looks like this:

in onCreate():

```
setActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And the menu method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tasks, menu);

    return true;
}
```

When the method inflates the menu and returns true, the 'up' navigation arrow works file; when the method returns false, the arrow is there, but clicking it doesn't do any thing. Is this some kind of an Android bug?

Comment: Why don't you just return true and skip inflating if `task.isEmpty()` ?

Comment: @user3249477: it does work indeed, thank you, it just didn't occur to me as a valid workaround. If you wrote an answer, I could accept it. Do you happen to know why returning false 'disables' the whole action bar? This seems strange.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's weird, because with the default ActionBar, up button continues working, but when using a Toolbar it doesn't once you return false.

Answer (score 2):

As a work around you can just skip inflating the menu altogether and return true.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

That being said, the documentation for `onCreateMenuItems(Menu menu)` suggests returning false as you initially tried to do should work. There is a bug tracking this issue right now: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=118700